# how to use the spark cluster computing function in servlets

Tags: tomcat, servlets, apache-spark

I am working on a dynamic web project. I want to write a servlet class to response to a frame submit request and perform some cluster computing tasks using apache spark(for example, calculating pi).
The doGet function of the servlet(named Hello) is as following

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String [] args=new String[2];
    args[0]="local";
    args[1]="4";
    double count=0;
    count=performSpark.cpi(args);
    //double count=3.14;
    String text1 =String.valueOf(count);
    response.sendRedirect("wresultjsp.jsp?text1=" + text1);  
}
```

The performSpark class is as following:

```
public class performSpark {
    static double cpi(String[] input)
    {
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(input[0], "performspark",
        System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), JavaSparkContext.jarOfClass(performSpark.class));

        int slices = (input.length == 2) ? Integer.parseInt(input[1]) : 2;
        int n = 1000000 * slices;
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            l.add(1);
        }

        JavaRDD<Integer> dataSet = jsc.parallelize(l);

        int count = dataSet.map(new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call(Integer integer) {
                double x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;             
                double y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
                return (x * x + y * y < 1) ? 1 : 0;
            }
        }).reduce(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call(Integer integer, Integer integer2) {
                return integer + integer2;
            }
        });

        double result=4.0 * count / n;      
        return result;
    }
}
```

The `spark-assemply-2.10-0.9.1-hadoop2.2.0.jar` is copied to `WEB-INF/lib`.
The build is successful but when I run the servlet in a tomcat7 server,the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` is reported when create the JavaSparkContext:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [Hello] in context with path
>   [/sparkdemo] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception]
>   with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>     at Hello.doGet(Hello.java:54)   at Hello.doPost(Hello.java:74)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)

Any one knows how to correct this problem?

Comment: You have to restart the service after changing anything under WEB-INF.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've try to restart the server,but the error still exist. Since no error happened when building the dynamic web project,I guess the spark-assemply jar is loaded successfully. But the ClassNotFoundException happened when creating JavaSparkContext. So I'm wondering whether there's something else dependency required for executing spark besides the spark-assemply jar.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've found the solution as follows.

When tomcat server starts, it loads the `spark-assemply-2.10-0.9.1-hadoop2.2.0.jar` and an error:`validateJarFile (.....) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec3.0 ......` is reported, which indicates that there exists some overlapped jar dependency.

Then I open the `spark-assemply-2.10-0.9.1-hadoop2.2.0.jar` and find an overlapped folder in javax/servlet. After delete the servlet folder, the `spark-assemply-2.10-0.9.1-hadoop2.2.0.jar` is loaded successfully in tomcat and the ClassNotFoundException is gone.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar use case in our project where in we want to submit user queries to spark interactively from a web project.
The way we achieved it was by first creating a spark session and attaching our custom servlet it to: .attachHandler()

In attachHandler method of our custom servlet we attached our Servlet class to ServletContextHandler of spark:

```
ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler();
HttpServlet servlet = new <CustomServlet>(spark);
ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(servlet);
handler.setContextPath(<root context>);
handler.addServlet(sh, <path>);
spark.sparkContext().ui().get().attachHandler(handler);
```

Now that the servlet has got attached to Spark UI say on port 4040, then u can submit requests to it directly. We overrode the doGet method of our servlet to accept a JSON containing SQL to be run, submitted SQL using
    ds = this.spark.sql(query);
Iterated over dataset returned, and added it to response object.

Another way to do this is to leverage Apache Livy.

Hope this helps.